# To update image for a particular list item

Tags: javascript, tizen-web-app

I am building a tizen app where a user can update his\her's vehicle details.Suppose we have a car called honda from a list of car.Clicking on a car name will take you to the page where you entered the details of that particular vehicle before.I want the user to be able to upload an image,say,RC book or whatever and storing that image to that particular vehicle only.How am I supposed to do that?I am able to select image from tizen,and I've used websql to update the path.But so far it's not working.Please help.ASAP

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Updating a second image and updating the path to the DB

Comment: I didn't get you. In description you mentioned that you want the user to upload the image. But now in comment you told to upload a second image? If possible kindly be specific n elaborative so that problem can be understood. With your description its not clear at all.